# min function regarding question in c++(CP & Dynamic programming)

Tags: c++

This is a function which solves how many coins are required to form a particular number. I.E we want to form the sum 6 by {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1} coins. What is the minimum number of coins needed to form 6?
Optimal solution in DP(Dynamic Programming):
4+2

**The question is why we are comparing a number with infinty?** in the best variable in the for loop.

```
int solve(int x)
{
    if (x < 0)
        return 100;
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;
    if (ready[x])
        return value[x];
    int best = INFINITY;
    for (int c : coins)
    {
        best = min(best, solve(x - c) + 1);
    }
    value[x] = best;
    ready[x] = true;
    return best;
}
```

Comment: Note that `minimum(a, b, c, infinity) == minimum(a, b, c)`.

Comment: There is no infinity in this code, there is a value that's named INFINITY (or a macro called INFINITY). Presumably it's set to a large integer number (perhaps INT_MAX from stdint.h), and `best` is initialized to this so that any solution found is guaranteed to be smaller than this.

Comment: `return 100;` should probably also be `return INFINITY`, otherwise you'll fail cases like "make 102 from coins {1, 200}".

Comment: I suggested `INT_MAX` for `INFINITY`, but that is a mistake, since that would cause overflows. Perhaps `INT_MAX/2`.

Comment: who is "we" ? Who wrote the code?

Answer (score 0):

`INFINITY` is the highest numerical float value which is available. That means, every number should be smaller than infinity. Since `best` needs to be initialized before usage, it makes the most sense to initialize it by the maximum value.

Comment: That can't be correct (that it's the highest numerical float value), since it's being assigned to an integer variable `best`.

Comment: there's no infinity for integer values

Comment: overlooked. But would be interesting what this define actually is, I assume something like INT_MAX.